# Min_Size for c3p0

Tags: java, c3p0

I'm developing a web app (3-tier). I'm currently using Hibernate as ORM and C3P0 as connection pooling mechanism. Browsing through the properties of C3P0, it looks like:

Min_size: Minimum number of JDBC connections in the pool.

I understand this would give "n" no.of.connections at any time. What I don't understand is, does this mean, if n+1 users want to access at the same time, would the system hang? Also, is there any benchmark for how this (min_size) should be decided?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Max connections is governed by a property called maxPoolSize.

```
<property name="initialPoolSize"                     >2</property>
<property name="minPoolSize"                         >1</property>
<property name="maxPoolSize"                         >5</property>
<property name="acquireIncrement"                    >1</property>
```

The above provides a pool with 2 connections to start with, maxing out at 5 concurrent connections, and adding 1 at a time when there are not enough to go around.

Anyone coming after 5 concurrent in the above example would wait (hang) until a connection became available. In practice, if you are using your connection pool properly (returning connections in between SQL calls, not running overly long queries, etc), then this isn't an issue. It does require knowledge of your application's usage profile.